# Como alocar uma quantidade imensa de memória?

Tags: c#, .net, criptografia, memória

Criei um algoritmo de criptografia OnFly que encripta bytes sem a necessidade de copiar-los para uma nova cópia destes mesmos bytes. Isso é tanto para encriptar e para decriptar estas listas de bytes. Como no esquema abaixo, a mesma cadeia que entra será a mesma que irá ser descriptada, fiz isso pensando no custo de memória que teria ao usar arquivos largos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, considere o arquivo **fileBytes** cujo há uma imagem PNG de 4 MB (4.194.304 bytes) armazenados nela. O meu algorítimo aumenta apenas **1 byte** do tamanho original, e encripta os demais bytes do arquivo, mantendo seu tamanho e aspecto.

Tanto para descriptografar, é descontado 1 byte neste arquivo.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, se eu usar um arquivo arbitrariamente grande na criptografia, além de usar um enorme uso de processador a memória do aplicativo será somada junto com o tamanho do arquivo, e se eu usar um arquivo de 10 GB num computador de 4GB de RAM será atirada uma exceção `OutOfMemoryException`.

Veja no exemplo abaixo como isso iria ocorrer:

```
// as keys em CRYRAZ também são outras Arrays de bytes.
byte[] key = new byte[] { 12, 51, 63}; 
// cria uma nova instância de CRYRAZ.
Cryraz clientCriptografia = new Cryraz(key);

// a mensagem que será usada para encriptar
string Mensagem = "Olá, mundo!";
// bytes da mensagem
byte[] Mensagem_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Mensagem);

// Mensagem_bytes será o nosso alvo. Atualmente ela se encontra decriptada e original, vamos encriptar ela agora.
Cryraz.EncryptData(ref Mensagem_bytes);

// Pronto, Mensagem_bytes está encriptado.
```

É assim que funciona Cryraz, diferente dos outros métodos de criptografia que você copia os bytes, assim obtendo a versão original e encriptada no mesmo código, diferente do Cryraz, ele encripta diretamente o original.

Esse é o corpo do método para encriptar (cortei partes desnecessárias de verificações e opções de segurança do algoritmo):

```
public void EncryptData(ref byte[] entryByteData) {
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i <= entryByteData.Length - 1; i++) {
        // ação recursiva em todos os bytes de entrada
        // é aqui a ação de criptografia
        // no final, o byte é atribuído à array:
        entryByteData[i] = ((byte)a);
        // obs: "a" é o novo byte encriptado
    }
    // aumenta o tamanho original da array para inserir o hash de segurança
    Array.Resize(ref entryByteData, entryByteData.Length + 1);

    // cria o hash de segurança e insere-o na array, sem esse hash, não há
    // descriptografia, é parte do algoritmo
    byte hash_x = performKeyHash(key);
    entryByteData[entryByteData.Length - 1] = hash_x;

    // coleta as variáveis inutilizadas
    GC.Collect();
}
```

> **Código completo:** https://pastebin.com/wKQn0S5N

Mesmo com o `GC.Collect();` no final do método fica uma enorme quantia de memória sendo usada no aplicativo, por causa de ler os bytes dos arquivos que serão usados.

> Para o algoritmo funcionar, é necessário saber o índice do byte em relação à array que está sendo criptografado e ter o tamanho exato da entrada e da saída.

## Em suma, como faço para que o aplicativo consiga "cachear" todos os bytes de um arquivo muito grande sem que haja problemas com memória? Existe uma maneira para "driblar" isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Óbviamente voce está proibido de ler o seu ficheiro inteiro duma só vez. A única alternativa que lhe resta é processar o ficheiro em blocos:

```
public static void Encripta(string src, string dest){
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
    File.Create(dest);
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    using(var reader = File.OpenRead(src))
    using(var writer = File.OpenWrite(dest))
    {
        int bytes;
        while((bytes = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0){
            //chama o seu encryptData com buffer aqui
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Voce também terá que adaptar o seu algoritmo atual. Quer a parte de encriptacao quer a parte de desencriptacao. Por aquilo que percebi sempre que encripta um array, o algoritmo adiciona um byte no fim (uma especie de checksum). Mas o problema agora é que voce só quer que isso seja feito no último array.

```
public static void Encripta(string src, string dest){
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dest));
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    var cipher = new Cryraz(new byte[]{10, 11, 12});

    using(var reader = File.OpenRead(src))
    using(var writer = File.Create(dest))
    {
        int bytes;
        while((bytes = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0){
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, bytes);
            //O algoritmo de encriptacao tem que ter um parametro adicional que indica se este é ou nao o último bloco.
            cipher.EncryptData(ref buffer, reader.Position == reader.Length);
            //chama o seu encryptData com buffer aqui
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        writer.Flush();
    }

}
```

Do mesmo modo o algoritmo de desincriptacao le sempre o último byte do array para obter o checksum. O problema é que o checksum só está presente no último array. O que isto quer dizer é que tem que ler o valor de antemao.

```
public static void Desencripta(string src, string dest){
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dest));
var buffer = new byte[4096];
var cipher = new Cryraz(new byte[]{10, 11, 12});

using(var reader = File.OpenRead(src))
using(var writer = File.Create(dest))
{
    reader.Position = reader.Length - 1;
    //le o checksum do fim do ficheiro, para decriptar todos os blocos
    var checkSum = reader.ReadByte();
    reader.Position  = 0;
    int bytes;
    while((bytes = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0){
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, bytes);
        cipher.DecryptData(ref buffer, (byte)checkSum);
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    writer.Flush();
}
```

[Código completo](https://pastebin.com/jA4q4hBD)

Comment: `int bytes` seria a atual posição do byte que foi corrido?

Comment: @CypherPotato Nao. É o tamanho de bytes que foi lido para o buffer. Se o ficheiro tiver por exemplo apenas 1000 bytes entao ele só vai entrar no `while` 1 vez e `bytes` terá o valor 1000

Comment: Fiz a implementação deste método na classe, mas não deu certo, o tamanho de saída do arquivo ficou maior que o tamanho original e a descriptografia descriptou o arquivo porém ele ficou corrompido. Não sei o que houve.

Comment: @CypherPotato Só o posso ajudar se publicar o código completo para encriptar e desencriptar.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com um link.

Comment: @CypherPotato Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Houve quebra. Implementei as mudanças na classe `Cryraz` e coloquei a classe `Sample` na classe de testes. Usei um vídeo de 25MB, então decifrei ele usando o código nativo, e o arquivo foi corrompido. Código: https://pastebin.com/5bCt4XRf

Comment: Gostei da ideia dos streams, mas não sei manipular streams. A minha ideia sugere ler todos os itens do stream normalmente, ignorando o último que seria o Hash, e no final da leitura, a validação do checksun seria feita. A mesma coisa seria para a decriptografia, fazer a operação byte-por-byte, e quando chegar no último byte, descarta-lo, pois já iria saber o que fazer com ele.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61799/discussion-between-bruno-costa-and-cypherpotato).